# Removing samaccountname from group after N time - powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking to find a way to remove a user from a group after a specific amount of time.

Via the below link I found that you can find users that were added with 10 days or more:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-the-time-a-user-was-a0bfc0cf#content

As an output I get the example below:

```
        ModifiedCount    : 2
        DomainController : DC3
        LastModified     : 5/4/2013 6:48:06 PM
        Username         : joesmith
        State            : ABSENT
        Group            : CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Com
```

I would like to return `SamAccountName` instead of Username.

I was trying to look at code and I know this is something to do with the variable `$pattern` But I am not that good in powershell to know at first sight.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that code, the `Username` property **IS** the SamAccountName.
However, if you want to change that label, you can either simply change it on line 106 from

```
Username = [regex]::Matches($rep.context.postcontext,"CN=(?<Username>.*?),.*") | ForEach {$_.Groups['Username'].Value}
```

into:

```
SamAccountName = [regex]::Matches($rep.context.postcontext,"CN=(?<Username>.*?),.*") | ForEach {$_.Groups['Username'].Value}
```

Or change the label in the objects returned afterwards with a calculated property:

```
$returnedObjects | Select-Object @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$_.Username}}, * -ExcludeProperty Username
```

Comment: Mhm yes but still it return me a "user logon name" but i want it to return me a pre-windows name

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski Well.. that was not what your question was about... If you want to search for users that have a mismatch of logon name and pre-windows 2000 logon name, you can use the returned SamAccountName property and do `Get-ADUser -Filter *  | Where-Object {($_.samaccountname + "@yourdomain.local") -ne $_.userprincipalname}`

Comment: Not exactly, i just want to get a pre-windows name becasue this is also a samaccountname. I will use this samaccountname to remove users from group.

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski from [here](http://blog.schertz.name/2012/08/understanding-active-directory-naming-formats/) _"The User Logon Name (Pre-Windows 2000) is the legacy format from Windows NT and is often referred to using the raw attribute name of sAMAccountName. This field is limited to a maximum of 20 characters and is used in conjunction with the legacy (or NetBIOS) domain name."_